# string.Format() Blank Zero

Tags: c#, zero, string.format

In my application, there are possibilities to format a string using the `string.Format()` function. I want to add the possibility to return blank when the result is zero.

As far as I can see, it is possible to do this using the code: `0.toString("0;; ");`, but as i already mentioned, I need to use the `string.Format()` function (since it must be able to use for example the `{0:P}` format for percentage.

Does anyone knows how to blank a zero value using the `string.Format()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you do it with `if else` statement?

```
string result = String.Format(the value);
if(result=="0")
{
   result=" ";
}
```

Comment: Because I do edit an existing application where a format can be filled in somewhere. Adding a new format is as easy as editing an xml configuration file. Adding an if else statement will do indeed, but ends up in editing the code on every place the format is used...

Comment: At the end, I have to use this solution. Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 13):

`String.Format()` [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719871%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) the `;` section separator.

Try e.g. `String.Format("{0:#%;;' '}", 0);`.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't mix standard and custom format strings like this.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Thank you for your answer. But this will return N when the value is 1, and -N when the value is -1 :(

Comment: @LukeH Does that mean that it is not possible to perform this?

Comment: @Peter: Can I clarify the requirements? If the number is non-zero then you want to apply the `P` standard format, but if the number is zero you want a blank?

Comment: @LukeH, you're right, the whole expression must be either standard or custom. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Peter, what do you want to print if the value is -1?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi the normal outcome, so in this case -100%

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi @LukeH Thanks for the updated answer. But the user of the application can choose several formats. One of them is currency, which ends up in the format {0:C}. This format will show a culture-specific result ($ in US, € in EU). However, a custom format cannot be culture specific. That's why I prefer standard expressions...

Answer (score 10):

My answer is a bit late, but you may want to try the following:

```
{0:#.##%;-#.##%;''}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned before, {0:P} is just an example the user can choose of. I have to make use of the standard formatting expressions, which is the reason I can't use this expression. However, thank you for your time!

Comment: this has the key insight which is that `''` can be used to specify the empty string since putting nothing after the semicolon is otherwise interpreted as the zero format having not been specified (and so defaults to the positive format).

Answer (score 0):

Or, perhaps more elegantly as an extension method on `int`:

```
public static class StringFormatters
{
    public static string ToNonZeroString(this int i) => i == 0 ? "" : i.ToString();
}
```

and then

```
(1+1-2).ToNonZeroString()
```